# Stride with different height and width in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow to process 1D signals (shape being `(?, 5000, 1, 12)`) and would like to perform stride operations. However, when I try `tf.nn.conv2d(input_variable, W, strides=[1, stride, 1, 1], padding='SAME')`, I get a ValueError:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/common_shapes.pyc in conv2d_shape(op)
    207   if stride_r != stride_c:
    208     # TODO(shlens): Add support for this.
--> 209     raise ValueError("Current implementation only supports equal length "
    210                      "strides in the row and column dimensions.")
    211 

ValueError: Current implementation only supports equal length strides in the row and column dimensions.
```

Is there a known workaround to the limits of the current implementation, which would allow me to have an horizontal stride only?

Answer (score 0):

We're working on supporting strides with different lengths.